# \longmapsto strange space

Tags: math-mode, relation-symbols

has anyone got this strange space appearing when using `\longmapsto` in either math mode or any math environment?
I have no idea why it appears or how to fix it. It does not happen with `\mapsto`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without any code, it's hard to tell where the problem comes from. Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) that reproduces the problem? It should be a compilable code, so it should start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: While preparing an example, I was debating on what packages to show, and I fixed it.
```\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}
  F: \mathcal{D} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d \nonumber \\
  x & \longmapsto \textbf{\textit{m}}_i
 \end{align}
 
\end{document}```

The problem is that 'breqn' package. If removed, it will output the ok result.

Comment: Great! You could write an answer based on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the package 'breqn'. Once removed, the symbol appears correct.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}  

\begin{document}    

\begin{align}       
   F: \mathcal{D} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d \nonumber \\ 
   x & \longmapsto \textbf{\textit{m}}_i    
\end{align} 
 
\end{document}
```